# Ambiguous Spark DataFrame schema - non JOINed scenario

Tags: apache-spark

Given that we can see the same Col name in a dataframe below - as I noted elsewhere:

```
root
  |-- week: string (nullable = true)
  |-- dim1: integer (nullable = false)
  |-- dim2: string (nullable = true)
  |-- t1: integer (nullable = false)
  |-- t2: integer (nullable = false)
  |-- t3: integer (nullable = false)
  |-- t1: integer (nullable = false)
  |-- t2: integer (nullable = false)
  |-- t3: integer (nullable = false)
  |-- t1_diff: integer (nullable = false)
  |-- t2_diff: integer (nullable = false)
```

and that:

```
df.select("t1").show(false)
```

returns ambiguous reference, then how can I state which one I want to select?

This is not a result of a JOIN, but just based on a Seq definition with .toDF(...) as follows:

```
val df = Seq(
         ("2016-04-02",14, null, 9784, 880, 23, 9789, 820, 45, -5, 60),
         ("2016-04-30",14, "FR", 9785,  13, 34, 9785,   9, 67, 90, 4),
         ("2016-04-16",14, "FR", 9785,  13, 34, 9785,   9, 67, -100, -123)
            ).toDF("week", "dim1", "dim2", "t1", "t2", "t3", "t1", "t2", "t3", "t1_diff", "t2_diff")
```

Somewhat inconsistent to me, and not something I would do, but I did note this, so more so out of curiosity. Seems an oversight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only was is to rename the columns of the dataframe.